# how can I change the font on Edit Post area (admin dashboard)

Tags: wp-admin, title, dashboard

I need to change the font family on the Edit Post title and post area title. how can I change it?
[image]

[image: need to add this area]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use admin_head action

```
function admin_css()
{
?>
<style>
//css Here
</style>
<?php
}
add_action('admin_head','admin_css');
```

Comment: I added it functions.php file, now it's work